# how to get only date if we have taken date and time both in python

Tags: python

I have a csv file which contains a date format like: `12/10/2011:02:03:20`. I have more than 10 data of date/time from which I only want to read like: `12/10/2011` for that I have read the csv file name code written to give the date is: `row[5]` is the column of my date/time.

```
Date=row[5]; 
df= datetime.datetime(Date)
df.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

but it's giving the error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Please help me how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

d = '12/10/2011:02:03:20' 
dt = datetime.strptime(d, "%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:%S") 
print(dt.date())
```

A reference of all the legal format codes:

> - Directive  - Description                 -  Example

- %d           Day of month 01-31          (12 here)
- %m           Month as a number 01-12     (10 here)
- %Y           Year, full version          (2011 here)
- %H           Hour 00-23                  (02 here)
- %M           Minute 00-59                (03 here)
- %S           Second 00-59                (20 here)

For more references : [Click here - Python Datetime](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp)

Comment: i'm gtting this error:AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: Try adding `from datetime import datetime` else use `dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series ...what is this error your way is working when i'm giving only one d = '12/10/2011:02:03:20' but i have more than one date time so i store it in one var and try to access it ..its not working

Comment: You can iterate the list of dates.

Comment: i have one more doubt that is it neccessary to give the correct format date/time coze i have taken a different way 12/10/2011:02:03:20 is it ok

Answer (score 0):

Use `strptime` to convert to datetime object then use `strftime`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime

df= datetime.datetime.strptime("12/10/2011:02:03:20", "%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
print(df.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

**Output:**

```
10/12/2011
```

Comment: If i give like:df= datetime.datetime.strptime(your_Variable).........I'm getting a error:TypeError: strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)....? I have more than one date so can not write like you i have created a variable "your_Variable" which all the date/time is stored.. when tried with above way i have witten its not working...

Comment: Are you providing both the date string and the date format as shown above?

Comment: no im giving the variable name whose contain all data

Answer (score 0):

Use strptime(), examples in doc.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html